# Change Excel chart legend text entry without editing the data?

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint presentation that I need to refine and it includes some charts from Excel (I did not make them). However, those charts were copypasted and the originals are no longer available - but some legend text entries are wrong because the data were modified in the meantime. Is there a way to change ONLY the entries without going on Excel and selecting the data? Basically doing it visually in some way? The data on Excel are still the same, it's only the name of the series the charts refer to that has changed, but doing the charts from scratch all over again would require quite a lot of time because the format of the original Excel tables is now completely different.

Essentially the charts are just fine, the colours are also fine, it's just one legend entry that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Copy as an image then edit using a picture editor.

But how was the data updated as you state it was modified then you say the data is still the same.

You could even make a dummy chart and create the legends in the correct font and size, then copy those and paste on the original image, done with an eye for detail and it won't be noticeable.

Comment: What I mean is, the data I want to show are the same, it's just their format and the name of the series that has changed. Basically rows, tables etc. But the data themselves and the results I wanna show (averages etc.) are the same.